# How to do ModelName.objects.filter in html

Tags: html, django, django-models

I'm trying to eliminate the amount of code I need to put in my view and want to do this in my html file:

```
{% for committee in c %}
    {% for article in Article.objects.filter(committee=committee) %}
    <a class="post-link" href="{% url 'update' id=article.id %}">{{article.title}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am passing my article model and list of c as context in my view.

But it gives me this error:

```
    TemplateSyntaxError at /admin-dash/
Could not parse the remainder: '(committee=committee)' from 'Article.objects.filter(committee=committee)'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin-dash/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '(committee=committee)' from 'Article.objects.filter(committee=committee)'
Exception Location: C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 662, in __init__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\benja\\Desktop\\mysite\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Tue, 12 Jan 2021 19:41:28 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\benja\Desktop\mysite\mysite\blog\templates\admin.html, error at line 18

Could not parse the remainder: '(committee=committee)' from 'Article.objects.filter(committee=committee)'
8       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/admin.css' %}">
9       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/posts.css' %}">
10  </head>
11  <main>
12  
13  
14      <div class="admin-panel">
15          <div class="posted">
16              <h1 style='font-size: 7rem; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 0;'>Posts:</h1>
17              {% for committee in c %}
18              {% for article in Article.objects.filter(committee=committee) %}
19              <h1>committee</h1>
20              <a class="post-link" href="{% url 'update' id=article.id %}">{{article.title}}</a>
21              {% endfor %}
22              {% endfor %}
23          </div>
24          <div class="drafts">
25              <h1 style='font-size: 7rem; margin-bottom: 20px;'>Drafts:</h1>
26      
27              <h1>Sustainability Committee:</h1>
28              {% for article in sc1 %}
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\Desktop\mysite\mysite\blog\views.py, line 89, in admin_view
        return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
```

Any idea how to do this? I think it's some sort of syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Share your `Article` model

Answer (score 0):

You access the related `Article` objects with:

```
{% for committee in c %}
    {% for article in committee.article_set.all %}
        …
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you use a relation like a `ForeignKey`, Django will automatically define a relation in reverse, for a `ForeignKey`, that will be the `modelname_set`, so in this case `article_set`. You can change the name of the relation in reverse by specifying the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

The above is however *not* efficient, since it will here make *N+1* queries: one query to obtain the `Committee`s, and for each `Committee` it will make an extra query to obtain the related articles.

In the view, you can use [**`prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch the related objects with a single extra query so:

```
c = Committee.objects.prefetch_related('article_set')
```

> I need to put in my view and want to do this in my html.

Django templates are deliberately restricted *not* to allow making function calls with parameters. This to avoid writing *business logic* in the templates, this belongs in the views, not in the templates.